# Getting stats of daily values ordered in fuzzy ranges

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Ok following task; I've got a table which has 3 columns, ID, UserID and Time, which is a DateTime-Type. Now I want to get the following statistics:

I've got 5 ranges:

- Morning (6am - 11.30am)
- Noon (11.30am - 2pm)
- Afternoon (2pm - 6pm)
- Evening (6pm - 10pm)
- Night (10pm - 6am)

A user has, as example, the following entries:

```
ID  UserID  Time
46  1       2011-11-17 17:51:24
47  1       2011-11-17 11:41:41
48  1       2011-11-17 07:31:20
49  1       2011-11-17 21:41:55
50  1       2011-11-17 21:58:28
99  1       2011-11-18 10:12:18
```

My target is, to get the following array:

```
Array (
 ['today']  => Array (
  ['morning'] => 1,
  ['noon'] => 1,
  ['afternoon'] => 1,
  ['evening'] => 2,
  ['night'] => 0
 )
 ['all']  => Array (
  ['morning'] => 2,
  ['noon'] => 1,
  ['afternoon'] => 1,
  ['evening'] => 2,
  ['night'] => 0
 )
 ['avg']  => Array (
  ['morning'] => 1.5,
  ['noon'] => 0.5,
  ['afternoon'] => 0.5,
  ['evening'] => 1,
  ['night'] => 0
 )
)
```

Well, it works if I really would iterate through a result set of all values of a user, but I bet there is an easier way via MySQL and its date functions. Also I get problems, if I try to take all entries and just want to get the times and not the datetimes. I need to parse it first via the php date functions and getting the time itself and thats really not useful, because I will probably get a few hundered thousands of those lines per userid.
The date itself has to be stored in the table for other tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest putting those date ranges into a table, in time fields

```
timenames:
id   name      start     end
1    Morning   00:06:00  11:29:59
2    Noon      11:30:00  13:59:59
etc...
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT timenames.name, timenames.start, timenames.end, COUNT(users.id)
FROM timenames
LEFT JOIN users ON (TIME(users.`Time`) BETWEEN timenames.start AND timenames.end)
GROUP BY timenames.id
```

which SHOULD give you a count of all events within each time-name's time range.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) construct which is similar to that in PHP. You could use that to give an identifier to each row based on the time value and then use the normal GROUP functions etc to return the data how you want it.

If the system has a really high to SELECT to INSERT/UPDATE ratio then you may want to consider [denormalising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalisation) the data to improve performance.

Comment: I also thought about storing the times as seconds from 0 to 86400 and the dates seperatly, but in some other cases this would lower the performance as well. So unfortunatly not an option. I will have a look at the CASE construct.